# MySQL query with large data performance

Tags: php, mysql, performance, pdo

I'm a bit new to MySQL and I would like to know if I'm going right with these tables and query:

## tb_anuncio

```
CREATE TABLE `tb_anuncio` (
  `anuncio_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `anuncio_titulo` varchar(120) NOT NULL,
  `anuncio_valor` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `anuncio_valorTipo` int(11) default NULL,
  `anuncio_telefone` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `anuncio_descricao` text,
  `anuncio_criado` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `bairro_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `anuncio_status` int(11) default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`anuncio_id`),
  KEY `ta001_ix` (`bairro_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT charset utf8;

ALTER TABLE `tb_anuncio`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `ta001_ix` FOREIGN KEY (`bairro_id`) REFERENCES `tb_bairro` (`bairro_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

## tb_estado

```
CREATE TABLE `tb_estado` (
  `estado_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `estado_nome` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `estado_criado` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `estado_url` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`estado_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `estado_url` (`estado_url`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

## tb_cidade

```
CREATE TABLE `tb_cidade` (
  `cidade_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `cidade_nome` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `cidade_criado` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `estado_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cidade_url` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`cidade_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `cidade_url` (`cidade_url`),
  KEY `tc001_ix` (`estado_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `tb_cidade`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `tc001_ix` FOREIGN KEY (`estado_id`) REFERENCES `tb_estado` (`estado_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

## tb_bairro

```
CREATE TABLE `tb_bairro` (
  `bairro_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `bairro_nome` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `bairro_criado` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `cidade_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `bairro_url` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`bairro_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `bairro_url` (`bairro_url`),
  KEY `tb001_ix` (`cidade_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `tb_bairro`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `tb001_ix` FOREIGN KEY (`cidade_id`) REFERENCES `tb_cidade` (`cidade_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Well I'm doing a query to show ads of a city/state, my query looks like:

## Query

```
select a.anuncio_id,a.anuncio_titulo,a.anuncio_valor,a.anuncio_valorTipo,a.anuncio_descricao
from tb_anuncio a inner join(
tb_bairro b inner join(
tb_cidade c inner join 
tb_estado d on d.estado_id=c.estado_id) on c.cidade_id=b.cidade_id) on b.bairro_id=a.bairro_id 
where a.anuncio_status=1 and d.estado_id=:estado_id and c.cidade_id=:cidade_id and b.bairro_id=:bairro_id 
group by a.anuncio_id 
order by a.anuncio_id desc 
limit :limit
```

I would like to know if I'm going right and it will work well when these tables get about 5k-10k of records.

I'm using PHP PDO MySQL.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know what an index is, and have you used one on your tables?

Comment: yes i know and i'm using :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it doesn't affect performance, the typical way to write a query would not have parentheses in the `FROM` clause.  Also, I doubt the `group by` is necessary:

```
select a.*
from tb_anuncio a inner join
     tb_bairro b
     on b.bairro_id = a.bairro_id inner join
     tb_cidade c 
     on c.cidade_id = b.cidade_id inner join 
     tb_estado e
     on e.estado_id = c.estado_id
where a.anuncio_status = 1 and e.estado_id = :estado_id and 
      c.cidade_id = :cidade_id and b.bairro_id = :bairro_id 
order by a.anuncio_id desc 
limit :limit;
```

You can simplify this, because you do not need all the `join`s -- the `join` keys are in referencing tables:

```
select a.*
from tb_anuncio a inner join
     tb_bairro b
     on b.bairro_id = a.bairro_id inner join
     tb_cidade c 
     on c.cidade_id = b.cidade_id 
where a.anuncio_status = 1 and c.estado_id = :estado_id and 
      c.cidade_id = :cidade_id and b.bairro_id = :bairro_id 
order by a.anuncio_id desc 
limit :limit;
```

Comment: Do u think that it will work fine with about 10k of records in each these tables?

Comment: @JessicaBelao . . . It should be fine.  The tables should be declared so the appropriate ids are primary keys.

Comment: primary keys are ok, isn't? every table has his own primary key, look above.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Portuguese, but seems like one estado contains many cidades, which contains many bairros.  If this is correct, then the schema is wrong.  Fixing the schema will lead to improving the performance.

There should be *one* bairro in the query, not *three* such items in the `WHERE`.

Furthermore, it is usually more practical for tb_bairro to include information about the cidade and estado, *not* tb_anuncio.

Once you have done those things, the `GROUP BY` can probably be eliminated, thereby adding more performance.

And add

```
INDEX(anuncio_status, bairro_id, anuncio_id)
```